# javascript array elements return values

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have this array:

```
[ 'lol',  { hola: 'xQaUqX19UmahiMd_3IN_', lol: 'PE-n5EmMl7jYYQrI3IOA' } ]
```

im triying to get the values "xQaUqX19UmahiMd_3IN_" and 'PE-n5EmMl7jYYQrI3IOA' dinamically but i cant do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you have an array and with that array you have an object. There are two array elements. You can access with 0 and 1 like below

```
var arr = [ 'lol',  { hola: 'xQaUqX19UmahiMd_3IN_', lol: 'PE-n5EmMl7jYYQrI3IOA' } ];
console.log(arr[0]); //prints  lol
console.log(arr[1]); 
// prints { hola: 'xQaUqX19UmahiMd_3IN_', lol: 'PE-n5EmMl7jYYQrI3IOA' } which is a object.
```

objects can be accessed with dots I think you know that. 
Now access like below.

```
console.log(arr[1].hola) // prints  xQaUqX19UmahiMd_3IN_
console.log(arr[1].lol)  // prints PE-n5EmMl7jYYQrI3IOA
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your array is stored in a variable named `myArray` then do `myArray[1].hola` or `myArray[1]['hola']`